# Font does not load using html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

on my website my font does not seem to be loading. I added the abel font family to my code. Here is a snippet of what i have tried.

```
<p style="margin-left: 620px; margin-top: -355px;"
        <span style="font-family: 'font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Random</span>
</p>
```

I have tried multiple things including css and nothing seems to work. I know this is a simple concept but i would just like to know how to fix it. I am using bootstrap aswell if that seems like it may cause an issue please tell me.

thanks

Comment: you have mixtures of `"` and `'` that may make it impossible for the css to be correct... eg the first string is `'font-family: '` I'd chewck that and jigger with the quoting to see if that helps. You probably don't need the `'` quotes around the `Abel`

Comment: It won't help that you have `font-family:` in that line twice.

Comment: Just in case... http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: Try like this - `<span style="font-family: Abel, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Random</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the server path of your font by css:

Check this post to know how to  do http://www.newvibe.ca/92weblessons

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  src: url('http://www.example.com/css/font/BebasNeue.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('http://www.example.com/css/font/BebasNeue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-
  opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('http://www.example.com/css/font/BebasNeue.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern
  Browsers */
  url('http://www.example.com/css/font/BebasNeue.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari,
  Android, iOS */
  url('http://www.example.com/css/font/BebasNeue.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /*
  Legacy iOS */
}
```

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: Can you try and put some summary of what's at that page here in case the link goes down? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span style="font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Random</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the style on the < p> tag not the span tag, I've had issues trying to do that in the past.
Also as an alternative might want to put your style in an external CSS file and just create a class that you assign to your p tag :)
external will make your life alot easier